# C# Regex to find and replace string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find occurrences of anything within [[...]] and replace with another string.
For example,
[[name]] lives in Florida.
[[name]] = James

I almost have it working, except for one small issue.

```
Regex.Replace([[name]], @" ?\[[.*?\]]", "James")
```

The output is: James] lives in Florida. The last ] is not being replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape *both* opening square brackets (and closing square brackets don't need): `\[\[.*?]]`.